# Traverse through loop to find repeated names

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have the following results from query and I a plsql block where I loop through the records and send_email to customers.

[image]

**Anonymous block**

```
FOR i IN (SELECT product_no, product_holder,product_catalogue FROM
product_master)
LOOP
mail_send('PRODMASTER',i.product_holder, i.product_no,i.product_catalogue);
END LOOP;
```

I would like to know what is the best approach if `product_holder` is repeating in query result then rather than sending multiple emails, would like to send one email with relevant details. E.g. In above case SMITH is repeated twice, so with above approach SMITH will get two emails, instead I would like to send one email to `SMITH` with `product_no`and `product_catalogue`

How can I do this?

Comment: PL/SQL Loop --> Row by Row aka Slow by Slow. Never do it in PL/SQL when the same could be done in SQL.

Comment: I'm just thinking, isn't there some list function that can be used in a group fuction, so that you can list values of each of the records, grouped togheter ? Basically, it's what the OP is asking. That way, it could be done in pure SQL.

Comment: Untested, this may be just that : http://www.williamrobertson.net/documents/one_row.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't do loops within loops in PL/SQL for this - use SQL to give you the data ready for use.

First we create your table with some test data (I'm guessing datatypes - you replace with your own) :

```
create table product_master (
   product_no        varchar2(10)
 , product_holder    varchar2(10)
 , product_catalogue varchar2(10)
)
/

insert into product_master values ('1', 'SMITH', 'TEMP')
/
insert into product_master values ('2', 'SMITH', 'TEMP')
/
insert into product_master values ('3', 'HARRY', 'ARCH')
/
insert into product_master values ('4', 'TOM'  , 'DEPL')
/
commit
/
```

What we want to send to `mail_send` procedure for each `product_holder` is a collection (array) containing `product_no` and `product_catalogue`. So first a type that contains those two elements:

```
create type t_prod_cat_no as object (
   product_no        varchar2(10)
 , product_catalogue varchar2(10)
)
/
```

And then a nested table type (collection type) of that type:

```
create type t_prod_cat_no_table as
   table of t_prod_cat_no
/
```

The procedure `mail_send` then should accept the `product_holder` and the collection type:

```
create or replace procedure mail_send (
   p_parameter        in varchar2
 , p_product_holder   in varchar2
 , p_product_cats_nos in t_prod_cat_no_table
)
is
begin
   dbms_output.put_line('-- BEGIN '||p_parameter||' --');
   dbms_output.put_line('Dear '||p_product_holder);
   dbms_output.put_line('Your products are:');
   for i in 1..p_product_cats_nos.count loop
      dbms_output.put_line(
         'Catalogue: '||p_product_cats_nos(i).product_catalogue||
         ' - No: '||p_product_cats_nos(i).product_no
      );
   end loop;
end mail_send;
/
```

(I just use dbms_output to simulate building a mail.)

Then you can in SQL do a `group by product_holder` and let SQL generate the collection containing the data:

```
begin
   for holder in (
      select pm.product_holder
           , cast(
                collect(
                   t_prod_cat_no(pm.product_no,pm.product_catalogue)
                   order by pm.product_catalogue
                          , pm.product_no
                ) as t_prod_cat_no_table
             ) product_cats_nos 
        from product_master pm
       group by pm.product_holder
       order by pm.product_holder
   ) loop
      mail_send(
         'PRODMASTER'
       , holder.product_holder
       , holder.product_cats_nos
      );
   end loop;
end;
/
```

The output of the above block will be:

```
-- BEGIN PRODMASTER --
Dear HARRY
Your products are:
Catalogue: ARCH - No: 3
-- BEGIN PRODMASTER --
Dear SMITH
Your products are:
Catalogue: TEMP - No: 1
Catalogue: TEMP - No: 2
-- BEGIN PRODMASTER --
Dear TOM
Your products are:
Catalogue: DEPL - No: 4
```

Doing it in SQL with a `GROUP BY` gives you everything in a single call from PL/SQL to SQL, which is a whole lot more efficient than first one call to get the distinct set of `product_holder`, loop over that, and then one call per `product_holder` to get the products for each holder.

UPDATE:

Added `order by` to the `collect` function in the above code to show you have control over the order that the data is populated in the collection.

Answer (score 1):

You can use two loops and send mail for each product holder, something like this;

```
FOR i IN (SELECT distinct product_holder FROM
product_master)
LOOP
 v_products := null;
v_catalogs := null;
for product in (SELECT pm.product_no, pm.product_catalogue FROM
                    product_master pm where pm.product_holder = i.product_holder)
loop
    if v_products is null then
        v_products := product.product_no;
    else
        v_products := v_products ||', ' ||product.product_no;
    end if;
    if v_catalogs is null then
        v_catalogs := product.product_catalogue;
    else
        v_catalogs := v_catalogs ||', ' ||product.product_catalogue;
    end if;
end loop;
mail_send('PRODMASTER',i.product_holder, v_products,v_catalogs);
END LOOP;
```